# How to stitch 2 lists together at a specific array index in python

Tags: python, arrays, list

In python looking for a way to stitch/merge/overwrite two lists together at a specific position.

```
A = [1,2,3,'No','No','No']
B = ['Yes 1','Yes 2','Yes 3']

#Want the following basically bringing B in at position 3 (0 Based)
C = [1,2,3,'Yes 1','Yes 2','Yes 3']
```

I know what extend does but it doesn't fit for this need and i'm a bit rookie at python.

Thanks Tim!

Comment: A better example would show a complete function call.

Comment: `C = A[:3] + B`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Non-destructive:

```
C = A[:3] + B
```

Destructive:

```
A[3:] = B
C = A
```

Comment: Thanks so much!!!  Perfect... I'm getting use to the slicing notation on strings/arrays still.  Come from other languages and python has all kinds of killer tricks.

Answer (score 1):

This should work taking advantage of python list slicing

```
def merge(a, b, index):
    a[index:] = b
    return a
```

Driver

```
A = [1,2,3,'No','No','No']
B = ['Yes 1','Yes 2','Yes 3']

print(merge(A,B,3))
```

> [1,2,3,'Yes 1','Yes 2','Yes 3']